# Set a property on an array of objects by an array of filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects

Let's say I have the following array:

```
var filters = ["id-12", "id-13", "id-50"];
```

And then an array objects:

```
var markers = [
{
  markerId: 'id-12',
  visible: true,
},
{
  markerId: 'id-13',
  visible: true,
},
{
  markerId: 'id-50',
  visible: true,
},
{
  markerId: 'id-132',
  visible: true,
},
{
  markerId: 'id-1512',
  visible: true,
}
];
```

I want to set the property visible to true on each object based on what was in the filter array, and the others to false when they don't match the filter.

I tried doing this with a simple for loop, but the problem is the orders of the filters don't match up during each iteration, so not all markers may get set to visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Array.prototype.map()` at this context,

```
markers = markers.map(function(itm){
  return  (itm.visible = (filters.indexOf(itm.markerId) > -1) , itm)
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gm5t8fmr/)

Or you can use a simple `for` loop,

```
for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
  markers[i].visible = filters.indexOf(markers[i].markerId) > -1;
}
```

Comment: why so overcomplicated?

Comment: @NinaScholz Does it looks over complicated than `!!~`? Your code and mine will run for O(n). I don't see any complication here.

Comment: you make an assignment to the same array, that is superfluous. the artray is already in the array, just a property has to be changed to the wanted value.

Comment: @NinaScholz  TBH, I didn't think of `forEach` initially. That should have been the right choice. Ok, lets give different solutions to OP. Nothing wrong in that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` function

```js
var filters = ["id-12", "id-13", "id-50"];

var markers = [ { markerId: 'id-12', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-13', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-50', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-132', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-1512', visible: true, } ];

markers = markers.map(function(e) {
    if (filters.indexOf(e.markerId) > -1)
        e.visible = true;
    else
        e.visible = false;
    return e;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(markers, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

---

Or `forEach` function with `ES2015` standard

```
markers.forEach(e => e.visible = filters.indexOf(e.markerId) > -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a superfluous assignment. Just use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var markers = [{ markerId: 'id-12', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-13', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-50', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-132', visible: true, }, { markerId: 'id-1512', visible: true, }],
    filters = ["id-12", "id-13", "id-50"];

markers.forEach(function (a) {
    a.visible = !!~filters.indexOf(a.markerId);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(markers, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `filters.indexOf(a.markerId) > -1` will be more readable than `!!~filters.indexOf(a.markerId)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `map` on each element in `markers` and set visible to whether `markerId` is in the `filters` array:

```
markers = markers.map(function(m) {
  m.visible = filters.indexOf(m.markerId) > -1;
  return m;
});
```